pod --version error can't satisfy 'rexml (~> 3.2.4)', already activated 'rexml-3.3.6'
when I run the pod --version command, I keep getting these error messages.
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1411:in `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'rexml (~> 3.2.4)', already activated 'rexml-3.3.6' (Gem::LoadError)
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `each'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1385:in `activate'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `block in activate_dependencies'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `each'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1385:in `activate'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:280:in `block in activate_bin_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:279:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:279:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.13.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Before it happened, all I did was fastlane update_fastlane.
I don't even know it's relevant.
I already trying to reinstall cocoapods and rexml using gem install rexml -v 3.2.4.
However if I try to uninstall cocoapods using gem uninstall cocoapods, then it says Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed.
I think something is really messed up here.
What can I do?

This question is similar to: `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'rexml' (>= 0) among 117 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Got the same error this morning, i've managed to fix it following this thread
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
cd ios
pod install --repo-update


sorry but which answer should i follow?

I've changed the post, you have either the link and the command that you should follow

it worked for me:
brew uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods


brew upgrade worked for me.

Just update the cocoapods to latest version. you can use
brew install cocoapods

or
brew update

or
brew upgrade cocoapods

